# How to Prevent False Messages From Displaying on Screen

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have tried multiple solutions and was able to reduce the print out of my error message, but it still prints and I can't seem to figure out how to hide this ugly message printed out by some C code being called by Python.  I have no control over the C code, so I can't change that.

I tried creating a context manager class to redirect all my output and set the `sys.tracebacklimit = 0`.  The trackbacklimit reduces the size of the output, but I still get the following message to show:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'SystemError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
AssertionError
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'SystemError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
AssertionError
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'SystemError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
AssertionError
```

The function actually isn't failing, it's just throwing false error messages so I need to hide the output.

Here is what I  have done:

```py
import sys
try:
    old = sys.tracebacklimit
    sys.tracebacklimit = 0
except:
    sys.tracebacklimit = 0
    old = 1000

def excepthook(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

old_except = sys.excepthook# = excepthook
sys.excepthook = excepthook

class suppress_stdout_stderr(object):
    '''
    A context manager for doing a "deep suppression" of stdout and stderr in 
    Python, i.e. will suppress all print, even if the print originates in a 
    compiled C/Fortran sub-function.
       This will not suppress raised exceptions, since exceptions are printed
    to stderr just before a script exits, and after the context manager has
    exited (at least, I think that is why it lets exceptions through).      

    '''
    def __init__(self):
        # Open a pair of null files
        self.null_fds =  [os.open(os.devnull,os.O_RDWR) for x in range(2)]
        # Save the actual stdout (1) and stderr (2) file descriptors.
        self.save_fds = [os.dup(1), os.dup(2)]

    def __enter__(self):
        # Assign the null pointers to stdout and stderr.
        os.dup2(self.null_fds[0],1)
        os.dup2(self.null_fds[1],2)

    def __exit__(self, *_):
        # Re-assign the real stdout/stderr back to (1) and (2)
        os.dup2(self.save_fds[0],1)
        os.dup2(self.save_fds[1],2)
        # Close all file descriptors
        for fd in self.null_fds + self.save_fds:
            os.close(fd)
```

I don't want anything to print out for my method.

Comment: might be worth saying you borrowed/stole that decorator from [somebody else](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/223).  what's wrong with it, it seems to do the right thing for me.  post the relevant part of the C code (or write your own that does the same), and how you're calling it, and maybe somebody can help.  but there's no way to replicate this at the moment

Comment: True, I can't post the C-code because I don't own it.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured it out. I did the following:

```py
import os
from contextlib import ExitStack, redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr, suppress
from io import StringIO
err = None
with ExitStack() as stack, suppress(Exception) as s3, suppress(ValueError) as s2, suppress(SystemError) as s1:
    null_stream = StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(null_stream) as s4:
        try:
            old = sys.tracebacklimit
            sys.tracebacklimit = 0
        except:
            sys.tracebacklimit = 0
            old = 1000
        stack.enter_context(redirect_stdout(null_stream))
        try:
            print('problem code here')
        except Exception as errmsg:
            err = errmsg
        finally:
            stack.close()
            sys.tracebacklimit = 1000
if err:
    raise err
```

I pushed all the messages to the StringIO and use the ExitStack() along with the suppress context to stop anything from showing. This does lead to a problem, so in the try/except/finally, I saved any real error and if it's not None raise that error.

It's not a great solution, but it works. I do not have access to the C-code as asked.